# How can I sync a changed SVN export back into the repository?

Tags: svn

An export of the repo was done, and then altered - files changed, added, and removed. If this was mercurial for example, I could delete the entire checkout, paste the export in, hit commit, and it would work out the differences. However, SVN has all those .svn folders around, so that approach won't work. I hit this problem quite frequently (migrating old websites) and resolving it manually is tedious and error-prone. Is there a quick way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Make a new checkout
- Do a folder diff to see which files were removed and delete those in SVN
- replace files in the checkout with the files in the export
- merge
- commit

Comment: +1 except for that last step.  Should be a 'commit' not merge.

Comment: that's assuming the repository hasn't changed in parallel to the export. Adding a final step -- commit